# prototype - how to delay a call to hide() by 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have the following code:

```
$('message').show();
$('message').hide();
```

How do I add a 10 second delay between the show and hide in prototype?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('message').show();
Element.hide.delay(10, 'message');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **[delay](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/delay/)** function